# Unexpected Token - Java Enum

Tags: java, enums

Is there any option in java to Create an enum with true and false like below,

```
public enum options {
true,
false,
both
}
```

Now getting unexpected token error as I am using true and false. thank you

Regards
haru

Comment: Alternatively you can represent your set of options by a `Set<Boolean>`, to which you can add one or both of `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. From [JLS 8.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), an enum constant is defined in the syntax to be

> ```
> EnumConstant:
>     {EnumConstantModifier} Identifier [( [ArgumentList] )] [ClassBody]
> ```

So it's an `Identifier`. And from [JLS 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), and `Identifier` is defined to be

> ```
> Identifier:
>     IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
> ```

Hence, an identifier is any valid string of identifier characters (basically letters and numbers, but with Unicode support thrown in) that is *not* a keyword (like `if`) or the words `true`, `false`, or `null`.

Realistically, you should be capitalizing your `enum` names anyway, so it would look more like

```
public enum Options {
  TRUE, FALSE, BOTH
}
```

which poses no issues as `TRUE` and `FALSE` aren't Boolean literals in Java.

Comment: thanks much for the information, so if I have to pass true as query parameter, and set this to the Enum, there is no other option, correct? As the enum, I can have TRUE, but the query param value is true. thanks

Comment: Correct. There's no way to have the `true` Boolean constant be a member of an `enum`. You'll have to write a conversion function to go between the two types. Though if your query parameter is `true`, `false`, or `both`, are you sure it's not a string? It might be a string you're ingesting that just happens to sometimes *look* like a Boolean.

Comment: thanks. Yes, it will be a string. thinking how we can set the true queryparam to the Enum TRUE, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The values of your enum should be formatted like constants; all-caps with underscores between words (if they are more than one word, which in your case, they are not). If you need to be able to convert them to/from strings that do not match the name and case of the enum constants, I would suggest adding a parameter with the string and methods to convert in each direction:

```
public enum Options {
    TRUE("true"),
    FALSE("false"),
    BOTH("both");
    
    private final String description;
    
    private Options(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    
    public static Options parse(String description) {
        for (Options option : Options.values()) {
            if (option.getDescription().equals(description)) {
                return option;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no such option: " + description);
    }
}
```

If you call `Options.parse("true")` it will return `Options.TRUE` and if you call `Options.TRUE.getDescription()` it will return `"true"`. If you call `Options.parse("none")` it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.